# word vba: select text between headings

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document in which I would like to select the full text of the heading starting with enumeration 2.3.1 until (not included) the heading 2.3.2 or [End of File]. If there are 'smaller' subsections or pictures or tables in between, they should also be selected.

PS: Example:

`...
2.2 Blah
Blah
2.3 Blubb
Blubb
[Start Selection]
2.3.1 Important1
Important2
[Picture: Important3]
[Table: Important4]
2.3.1.1 Important 5
Important 6
[Stop Selection]
2.3.2 Blieh`

I have experimented with navigating through every paragraph, but this is quite slow. I need this feature to copy the selection afterwards (I already know how to do that ;-)).

Thank you very much for help!

Jan

Answer (score 4):

This seems to work well.
Adjust the format setting so that it finds '2.3.1' etc. only in that given format type.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Caption 1")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "2.3.1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart

    Dim r1 As Range
    Set r1 = Selection.Range

    ' keep format settings, only change text
    Selection.Find.Text = "2.3.2"
    If Selection.Find.Execute Then
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    Else
        Selection.WholeStory
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    End If
    Dim r2 As Range
    Set r2 = ActiveDocument.Range(r1.Start, Selection.Start)
    r2.Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the VBA Macro I'm using to select the text between headings. However, it only selects between any two headings of any level. It won't include smaller subheadings.

```
Sub SelectBetweenHeadings()
    With Selection
        .GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToPrevious
        .Collapse
        Dim curRange As Range
        Set curRange = .Range
        .Extend
        .GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToNext
        If .Range = curRange Then
            .EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        End If
        .ExtendMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: fantastic! exactly what I needed... having a "template" which users can use both in oneNote or Word. This way it'll be easy to "update" the oneNote Version of it